# My computers aren't talking to each other

Tags: networking, ipconfig

Here's the IPConfig:

> Computer 1:
>
> IP address 192.168.110.101
>
> Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
>
> Default gateway 192.168.110.1

---

> Computer 2:
>
> IP address 192.168.111.102
>
> Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
>
> Default gateway 192.168.110.1

I have no idea about networking stuff. Please help

Comment: What do you mean they are not talking to each other? How did you determine that?

Comment: What do you mean by "not talking to each other?" What service are you trying to use? What are you trying to accomplish over the network? Try to "ping 192.168.110.101" from the command line of Computer 2, and vise versa. What do you get?

Comment: Recommended reading: [http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).

Answer (score 2):

*192.168.**110**.101/255.255.255.0* and *192.168.**111**.102/255.255.255.0* are two different networks.

As-written in the question 192.168.111.102 won't make it *anywhere*, since it's Gateway is on a different network (192.168.110.x)

Either make them something like 192.168.110.101 and 192.168.110.102 (with mask 255.255.255.0), or change both masks to 255.255.0.0 to widen the scope of the network.

Perhaps check out [this Wikipedia article on subnetting IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#IPv4_subnetting) for more info.